# Evaluating python's UnivariateSpline on complex data

Tags: python, scipy, complex-numbers, cubic-spline

I used `scipy` to interpolate some real data. I wished to evaluate fitted spline on some complex data, is there some trick to force `scipy` to do it? If not, are there some python packages that provide this functionality?

`import scipy.interpolate as inter
spl = inter.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline( x, y )`

When trying to evaluate it on complex `1.0j` a casting error in `_fitpack._spl_` fires up.

Answer (score 0):

A spline is a **piecewise** function defined separately on certain **intervals of real line**. Plugging complex values into a spline makes no mathematical sense. This is not a SciPy limitation; the value of a spline for non-real arguments is **undefined**.

If you want to fit a function and then plug a complex value in it, a spline is a wrong tool for the job. You can fit a polynomial or any non-piecewise model that is defined for complex arguments.

Comment: Why it does not have mathematical sense? In some sense it may be thought of as analytical continuation of real function into complex plane. Yes, spline is a piecewise polynomial function, it seems pretty easy to insert a complex value in polynomial in each piece...

Comment: Okay, let's try it with this simple spline: f(x)=x if x>=0, f(x)=-x if x<0. Given the complex number i, what piece should I plug it in? One gives i, the other -i.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted to do this with a complex number. My solution was to spline the real and the imaginary part independently:

```
spline_real = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(t_in, in_.real)
spline_imag = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(t_in, in_.imag)
out_real = spline_real(t_out)
out_imag = spline_imag(t_out)
```

Then combine to complex numbers again.